# How do I handle RapidXml errors?

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml

RapidXml throws an exception in case of an invalid XML file. Is it possible to recover from such a failure?

For example, is it possible to check if the XML is valid beforehand, or recover and continue on?

It seems that when such failures happen, there is only assert and exit of process, and no chance for recovery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, RapidXML raises exceptions on parse errors; it doesn't assert (perhaps by assert you just meant the process aborts).

It is possible to configure RapidXML with [your own error handler called `rapidxml::parse_error_handler`](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_ff5d67f74437199d316d2b2660653ae1_1ff5d67f74437199d316d2b2660653ae1) if you `#define RAPIDXML_NO_EXCEPTIONS` before including the RapidXML headers, and if such an error handler returns, RapidXML will call `assert(0)`, but I suspect that you don't have that enabled and you just need to be catching the right exception.

There's just one exception to catch for parse errors, and it's called [`rapidxml::parse_error`](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#classrapidxml_1_1parse__error), but RapidXML will also throw [`std::runtime_error`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/runtime_error/) if it fails to find the file.

Here's an example which catches both exception types, plus some catch-all handlers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rapidxml.hpp"
#include "rapidxml_utils.hpp"

int main()
{
    try
    {
        rapidxml::file<> xmlFile("test.xml");
        rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
        doc.parse<0>(xmlFile.data());
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Runtime error was: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const rapidxml::parse_error& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Parse error was: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error was: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "An unknown error occurred." << std::endl;
    }
}
```